# Knockout Mapping: Why does apply bindings clear values from my nested objects?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a KO model with a lot of nested objects and collections of nested objects. I use the `ko.mappings` mapping options to make sure they get properly generated during model creation, but the value gets cleared. Trying to start with a simple drop down menu and bind objects to it:

```
<select id="myList" name="SelectedSurvey" id="SelectedSurvey" class="form-control"
 data-bind="options: AvailableSurveys, optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedSurvey, 
optionsCaption: '-- Select Survey --'"></select>
```

Then, take some data, when creating a new object on the page, it works fine, but when trying to edit an existing record from the same page, the drop down value is never selected. When I check `viewModel.SelectedSurvey() the value is undefined, but it only becomes undefined after I call`applyBindings()`. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wLcr52y/3/

If you open the console and run it, you'll see the log before `applyBindings()` is called the full ViewModel, and the nested object `SelectedSurvey()` are properly komapping objects that have values, but then after it's called. `SelectedSurvey()` becomes undefined and as such my dropdown list never has a selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedValue parameter doesn't seem to want to accept an object as a valid value. It therefore clears the SelectedValue observable as soon as you apply bindings thinking that no valid value was provided.

As a workaround, I created a solution that uses the **optionsValue** parameter to accept the 'Id' property as a value. This will allow you to maintain control over which survey is selected by passing in merely an 'Id' value as opposed to an entire Survey object.

This requires that you update your Knockout version to 3.4.0. Are you locked in to using 2.2.1 for any reason?

I also updated your jsfiddle to include more readable implementation of the mapping plugin. Hopefully this will fix your issue:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.AvailableSurveys = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.AvailableSurveys);
    self.SelectedId = ko.observable(data.SelectedSurvey.Id);
    self.SelectedSurvey = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < self.AvailableSurveys().length; i++) {
            if (self.AvailableSurveys()[i].Id() === self.SelectedId()) {
                return self.AvailableSurveys()[i];
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/v1L5tw6h/3/

Comment: This works, but I'm quite frustrated with how ko/ko.mapping works. Why is there a difference between create vs editing functionality in whether you supply something with a value first or not. I've this problem anytime there is a nested object or nested collection of objects when trying to initialize it. For instance, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6wLcr52y/6/ The subscribe method, it won't set the selectedSurvey on load, but if you chose it by changing the dropdown, it works fine and sets the entire object.

Comment: I guess I should ask for clarification on when to use the mapping plugin vs not, because you use both plain observable and the ko.mapping.fromJS. I think that part is messing me up. In my normal experience, when working with nested objects, and attaching a subscribe method to them, when editing the record, I would get a "SelectedSurvey is not a function" error message. If a nested object was subscribed too like in my original fiddle. I thought this was because mapping plugin didn't wrap it enough and every property should be a mapping property (by wrapping it so it has a ko_mapping_ property).

Comment: The only time you would need to use the mapping plugin is whenever you need the child properties to be observables themselves. For instance, if you intend on updating Survey names on the fly, and you want those updated names to be reflected in the GUI, you would need the mapping plugin to generate your self.AvailableSurveys object. The reason I used a plain observable for the self.SelectedId property is because the Id field doesn't have any children to convert to observables, so it is pointless to use the mapping plugin on it.

Comment: As far as the self.SelectedSurvey object goes, it is returning a child of self.AvailableSurveys, which has already been mapped using the plugin, so your self.SelectedSurvey object should already have its properties mapped to observables and can be updated on the fly. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: On your first question involving setting the SelectedSurvey property via code...I've had trouble myself setting the SelectedValue whenever the value is a complex object. It just doesn't seem to accept the object as a valid value. Either you and I are doing something wrong when we try to set the value, or it is a limitation of Knockout itself, but either way, I don't think it has anything to do with whether you used the mapping tool or not. I could be wrong on that, I haven't experimented with it lately. I usually just use the workaround that I showed you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, in regards to using mapping or not, haven't you run into problems though when you try and take your whole viewmodel from server side code as JSON and convert it using mapping? It seems to handle nested objects and null values poorly, the mapping's mapping configuration helps this, but even so, in my real project I was able to remove all JS errors by calling ko.mapping.fromJS() on all nested properties instead of declaring then just plain observables, when using just plain obseravbles  I got the `x is not a function` when trying to apply events or grab their values.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I haven't experienced that particular issue. Usually I try to avoid mapping an entire view model from JSON. I'll usually manually declare as many of the observables as I can, and reserve the mapping plugin for specific objects or arrays that contain nested structures. The main reason I do it that way is for readability. I want the programmer who comes in behind me to be able to easily see what is going on in the view model, and its kind of hard to see what is going on when the mapping plugin abstracts the entire thing in background.